# Is this an equivalent definition of the coarsest topology on $E$ such that every $f\in \mathcal F$ is sequentially continuous?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, definition

Let $(E, \tau)$ be a topological space. Let $\mathcal F$ be a collection of real-valued functions on $E$. After reading [weak convergence of measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures), I feel that the following result is true, i.e.,

> Below statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. For all $x, x_n\in E$ with $n \in \mathbb N$, we have $x_n \to x \iff [f(x_n) \to f(x) \quad \forall f \in \mathcal F]$.
> 2. $\tau$ is the [coarsest topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_topologies#Definition) on $E$ such that every $f\in \mathcal F$ is [sequentially continuous](https://planetmath.org/sequentiallycontinuous).

Clearly,

- $(1)$ implies that every $f\in \mathcal F$ is sequentially continuous.
- $(2)$ implies that for all $x, x_n\in E$, we have $x_n \to x \implies [f(x_n) \to f(x) \quad \forall f \in \mathcal F]$.

I'm stuck at

- $(1)$ implies $(2)$: $\tau$ is the coarsest among those topologies that make every $f\in \mathcal F$ sequentially continuous.
- $(2)$ implies $(1)$: for all $x, x_n\in E$, we have $[f(x_n) \to f(x) \quad \forall f \in \mathcal F] \implies x_n \to x$.

Could you elaborate how to prove above result in case it is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true, using essentially the same counterexample as I gave for your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586499/is-there-the-coarsest-topology-tau-on-x-such-that-each-f-ix-tau?noredirect=1&lq=1).  Consider $E=\mathbb{N}$ and the inclusion map $E\to \mathbb{R}$.  Clearly the discrete topology on $E$ satisfies (1), but there is no coarsest topology on $E$ that makes the inclusion sequentially continuous.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I got it.