# Is there the coarsest topology $\tau'$ on $X$ such that each $f_{i}:(X, \tau') \to (Y_{i}, \tau_i)$ is sequentially continuous?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, continuity

Given a set $X$ and an indexed family $(Y_{i}, \tau_i)_{i \in I}$ of topological spaces with functions $f_{i}: X \rightarrow Y_{i}$. The [initial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology#Definition) $\tau$ on $X$ induced by the collection $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ is the *coarsest* topology on $X$ such that each
$$
f_{i}:(X, \tau) \to (Y_{i}, \tau_i)
$$
is continuous. Such $\tau$ does exist and $\{f_i^{-1} (O_i) \mid i\in I, O_i \in \tau_i\}$ is its [subbase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase#Definition).

> Is there the coarsest topology $\tau'$ on $X$ such that each $f_{i}:(X, \tau') \to (Y_{i}, \tau_i)$ is [sequentially continuous](https://planetmath.org/sequentiallycontinuous)?

If the answer is YES, then clearly $\tau' \subset \tau$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  For instance, consider the case where $X=Y=\mathbb{N}$ and you just the identity map $X\to Y$ where $Y$ has the discrete topology.  Then you are asking for a coarsest topology on $\mathbb{N}$ such that only the eventually constant sequences converge (to their eventual value).  Now take any non-discrete countable space in which only the eventually constant sequences converge (for instance, the [Arens-Fort space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arens%E2%80%93Fort_space)).  Transporting this topology to $\mathbb{N}$ along arbitrary bijections, we see that for any nonempty coinfinite subset $A\subset\mathbb{N}$, there is a topology on $\mathbb{N}$ in which $A$ is not open and only the eventually constant sequences converge.  So, the coarsest such topology would have to contain only cofinite sets and the empty set.  But in the cofinite topology, every sequence which takes infinitely many values converges (to every point), so this topology cannot actually work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! I have a closely related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586462/is-this-an-equivalent-definition-of-the-coarsest-topology-on-e-such-that-every). If you don't mind, please have a look at it.